# Issues with radio buttons in xcode

Tags: objective-c, radio-button, xcode4.5

I am having an issue with the radio button in ios in xcode.I would like to implement this with the help of two buttons(images on the buttons).How would i make the two buttons like  radio buttons?Any help?

Comment: what you would like to do with 'two radio buttons' , can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[radioBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[radioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myfunc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:radioBtn];
```

Comment: You missed addSubview, I did that for you.. :)

Comment: Thnx for ur answer..But my concern is how do i manage to  change the images between two buttons basically the control...because when one button is in uicontrolstatenormal others will be in selected mode and vice versa..thnx in advacnce

Comment: what about a loop over all other btns with command: [btn setSelected:NO];?

Comment: So basically we need to set a bool value to have atrack to which one is pressed and released.